# Spotify Listening-time

Tags: spotify

Is there any way to see how much listening-time a Spotify free account user has left, using spotifys apps api?

If possible, I would like to hinder specific flows in my spotify app when a user has no, or very little, listening time left.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I believe that this is not possible at the moment.